# Get ID element from url and store it in a session array every time page loads

Tags: reactjs, session-storage

In reactjs, I am trying to store the id to session storage array which comes from URL, for example, http://localhost:3000/#/carnivallist/171 what's the solution to store all the ids?

I can only store one id. when the page refreshes the id is getting replaced on the session storage.

```
componentDidMount() {


        if(this.props.params.id) {
            let pro_id=[this.props.params.id];
            console.log(pro_id);

            console.log("otem");
            let items=sessionStorage.getItem("carnival_dones");
            console.log(items);
            if(items!=""){
                this.setState({ carnival_done: [...this.state.carnival_done,{carnival_done:pro_id}]});

            }else{
                this.setState({carnival_done:pro_id});
            }

        }
    }
```

I expect to get all ids in an array but the session storage stores only the last value get saved. and the value not accessible through the session get method

Comment: How are you storing values?

Comment: @Zicsus in render I have given sessionStorage.setItem("carnival_dones",this.state.carnival_done);

Comment: Are you trying to store a array of 'carnival_done' like ['20', '30', '40'] or something like this [{carnival_done: '20'}, {carnival_done: '30'}, {carnival_done: '40'}]

Comment: @Zicsus like [20,30,40]

Comment: Then the way you are setting state is wrong. see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was using the
componentDidMount method instead of using componentWillMount so I found a solution changing the hook

```
 componentWillMount() {
    if(this.props.params.id) {
        let pro_id=[this.props.params.id];
        console.log(pro_id);

        console.log("otem");
        let items=sessionStorage.getItem("carnival_dones");
        console.log(items);
        if(items!=null){
            this.setState({carnival_done:[...this.state.carnival_done,[items,pro_id]]});
            //this.setState({ carnival_done: [...this.state.carnival_done,pro_id]});
            console.log(this.state.carnival_done);
        }else{
            this.setState({carnival_done:[pro_id]});
        }


    }

}
```

Thank you so much for your support

Answer (score 0):

You would have to save an array, something like below code:

```
let items = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("carnival_dones"));
if(!items){
 items = []
}
items.push(this.state.carnival_done)
sessionStorage.setItem("carnival_dones",items);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try saving array as json and parse it when retrieving.

```
componentDidMount() 
{
    if(this.props.params.id) 
    {
        let pro_id = this.props.params.id;
        let items = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("carnival_dones"));        

        if(items)
        {
            this.setState({ carnival_done: [...this.state.carnival_done, pro_id]});
        }
        else
        {
            this.setState({carnival_done: [pro_id]});
        }
    }
}

// Save session
save = () =>
{
    sessionStorage.setItem("carnival_dones", JSON.parse(this.state.carnival_done));
}
```